# Kafka Connect, plugin path

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How do I override the PLUGIN_PATH correctly so that after starting docker I can add an external connector?
/home/madmin/connectorf - path on my PC with jar - connector
CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH - default variable by confluent
Thanks for answers.

```
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      volumes: -/home/madmin/connectorf:/usr/share/java
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't want to mount your local connectors over the existing `/usr/share/java` folder. Try this instead:

```
    CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/usr/share/local-connectors" 
volumes: -/home/madmin/connectorf:/usr/share/local-connectors
```

Remember that connectors need to be present *before* the worker starts up; you can't set the local path and then add new ones once it's started running.

Another option is to install them in the container directly, [like this](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/rail-data-streaming-pipeline/docker-compose.yml#L130-L159)

```
    command: 
      - bash 
      - -c 
      - |
        confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-elasticsearch:11.0.0
        #
        echo "Launching Kafka Connect worker"
        /etc/confluent/docker/run & 
        #
        sleep infinity
```

Comment: Maybe I have another version of image. I didn`t find this folder on my docker
/usr/share/local-connectors

Comment: That's the point; `/usr/share` exists, and the `volume` command mounts the local folder into `/usr/share/local-connectors`.

Comment: If this answered your question then please make sure you mark it as such so that others can find it more easily :)